# Missing compileSdkVersion for google mobile ads

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, google-mobile-ads

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.ringit2"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Here is what I found on my build.gradle and I can't find `compileSdkVersion` which I have to change to at least 28 in order for `google mobile ads` to operate.

After I added `google_mobile_ads: ^1.1.0` on pubspec.yaml and imported the package to the `main.dart`, The app opens as I run the simulator but shuts down right away. Console shows me this message and it is stuck just like this forever.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G950N in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
```

Please note that my `ext.kotlin_version` is `'1.6.10'` because people have recommended to upgrade it

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

Also changed the distributionUrl...

[image]

Not sure why google mobile ads package is so hard to use even just to start but what should I change to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also using kotlin version '1.6.10' and compilesdk version is inside android>app>build.gradle

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The compileSdkVersion will be inside
android>app>build.gradle
inside that you can see compileSdkVersion in line 30

Also check your environment path of flutter